# Ionic Custom Login Page With Microsoft Azure Active Directory

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, active-directory, angular-ui-router, adal

1. I created custom login view with ionic framework. I want the user to sign in to the app using Microsoft Azure Active Directory. Is this possible? I also using coucbdb to post my todos that I have created in my form. The app is a todos app with two tabs of viewing all the todos and another one to create.
2. **What I have tried:** I am facing a problem with Active Directory [Adal Apache Cordova](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-cordova). The user can sign in and sign out of the app. The user is still available to see the content on the app when they hit the back button on the mobile device when they are signed out. I disabled the back button on the mobile device but it only works when you’re on the views of the app and not on the sign out page by Microsoft. I don’t want my users to be available to see the other views when they sign out or not even authenticated. I also can’t use [ADAL for JavaScript](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js) because it is not meant for hybrid apps.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my understanding, we need to implement the business logic ourselves to protect the views.

For example, we can determine whether show the views based on the token retrieved by the **Active Directory Authentication Library (ADAL) plugin for Apache Cordova apps** like code below:

```
var authContext = new Microsoft.ADAL.AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/common");
authContext.tokenCache.readItems().then(function (items) {
  console.log("Num cached items: " + items.length);
});
```

And to sign-out the apps, you can refer the recommendation of this library like below:

> Similar to native labraries the plugin does not provide special method to sign out as it depends on server/application logic. The recomendation here is
>
> Step1: clear cache
>
> `var authContext = new Microsoft.ADAL.AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/common"); authContext.tokenCache.clear()`;
>
> Step2: make `XmlHttpRequest` (or open InAppBrowser instance) pointing to the sign out url. In most cases the url should look like the following: `https://login.windows.net/{tenantid or "common"}/oauth2/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri={URL}`

Comment: I have implemented that it doesn’t work to protect the views in the app once you sign out. It works when you open the app because it takes you to the login page. Once you sign you can navigate through the pages. Then when you sign out and hit the back button it still allows you to view the pages. I want something like Adal Angular that allows you to check if the user is sign in when clicking the back button or on a link in the app.

Comment: What did you mean for the **back button**? Is it a button on the browser when you test the app or the button you add it into your app? Based on my understanding, if you add the back button into your app, it used the states, it should work after you sign-out the page.

Comment: I meant the back button that the tablet comes with on the android device. I can disable the back button on the android device. When the app is running, I can logout and I am redirected to the main logout page of Microsoft. That is when my settings for disabling the back button on the actual device isn’t disabled.

Comment: @JoseCabrera How did you protect and sign-out the app? We can protect the page by checking whether there is a id_token in the cache. When we sign-out the page, first we need to clear token cache, then send a sign-out request to Microsoft, after Microsoft sign-out the account it will redirect back to our app. There is no id_token in the cache this time. Did you mean that you end the  processing of sign-out when the page redirect to the Microsoft by clicking the back button?

Comment: Is there a specific way to protect my routes to constantly check if a user login? Example: Users opens app and is redirected to the Microsoft Login page, He/she signs in and available to view pages. When they click logout, it runs the function that you posted to clear the token Cache. Then they are redirected to Microsoft confirm logout page.  They are still available to view the pages if they click the back button on the actual device.

Comment: The authentication business logic should be executed every time when the HTML document is loaded.  Can you check the code was executed after you click the back button?